Swift 6 atomic cache with actors
I am building a Swift-on-server project that will use a cache. There are libraries for caches based on Redis and other data stores, but as far as I can tell, none of them are atomic.
It seems like Actors are just the ticket here, but I'm not getting over the finish line.
Getting an item from cache should be a process something like:

If the key is defined in cache, return it.
If the key is not defined, but another process is creating the data, wait until that is finished, and return the result.
If the key is not defined, and no other process is defining it, calculate the value and put it into cache.

Actors seem like a good solution to this problem, almost. Imagine an actor something like (this is pretty much swifty pseudocode, but it shows a rough outline of the process):
actor CacheItem {
    private let key: String
    private let storage: <Storage Class of choice>

    private var value: String?

    init (key: String, backingStorage: <Storage Class of choice>) {
        // set the stuff
    }

    func get() async -> String {

        if let value {
            return value
        }

        return await fillIfNotExists()
    }

    // this mutates the actor, so should force anything trying to read `value` to wait
    func fillIfNotExists() async -> String

        return storage.get(key).flatMap { response in
            if let value = response {
                return response
            }
        
            // Create the value (will potentially include asynchronous calls as well)
            value = // ...

            await storage.set(key, to: value)
                
            return value
        }

    }
}

However, the documentation says (emphasis mine),

... code that doesn’t include await and that’s inside an actor can make the updates without a risk of other places in your program observing the temporarily invalid state."

There is more discussion on that page about the way threads are used for actors, and it sounds like it depends on control not being yielded on that thread during the mutating function.
Reading and writing from cache will definitely be asynchronous. Is that going to break the atomicity of my CacheItems? Is there a workaround, maybe with added state in the CacheItem, to get the desired behavior?
Edit to add thank you to @duck in the comments for adding reentrancy to my vocabulary. Reading more has led me to believe at this time that Actor is simply not the tool for this job. I'm now thinking about an Actor that (waves hands) is a broker for mutex keys.

Actor has reentrancy feature so if you want to If the key is not defined, but another process is creating the data, wait until that is finished, and return the result., my suggestion is consider using a queue to store pending key and value and after an item stored, you can proceed next item in queue

Interesting, and thanks. If I understand correctly, then only one value could be generated at a time. That is not ideal in any case, but in this case some of those values depend on other very slow services. I will definitely look at the reentrancy feature.

Oh sorry but I misread your code, thought CacheItem is a wrapper around storage class, anyway to ensure atomicity for storage class, you should consinder make a cache manger as actor, not an item as an actor

I imagined one actor as a thread-safe entity to vend other actors that were atomic CacheItems. I was saving the CacheItem lifecycle for another question. Perhaps a pool? Anyway, if there is not a way for actors to make cache access atomic on an item level, there's really no point in figuring out how best to manage them.

You can certainly  implement a cache with an actor. Or with utilising a lock-free data structure (lock-free hash table), or with a class using an internal mutex, or utilising DispatchLib. But none of these would automatically solve all the problems you may encounter. There are semantically differences, though: the interface to an actor or DispatchLib is inherently asynchronous, while a solution with a mutex is synchronous & blocking. Besides this, I would make the Catche Items plain old data (or a type parameter for a generic cache), not actors itself - or anything that executes logic.

In Protect mutable state with Swift actors, there are some code samples associated with 11:59 in video. (Not the code in the video, itself, but the accompanying code on the third tab under the video on the web site.) There, they show an example of an enum with associated values, that can solves the reentrancy problem (and it also solves the problem of duplicative requests). Now that is an example with a cache of images fetched from some network source, but the idea can apply here, too.
